# Reusable HOC that takes multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I have this simple Higher-Order Component that works fine but it only accepts a single component:

```
let VerticalSlider = (Komponent) => {
  return (props) => (
    <div className='slider'>
      <Komponent {...props}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How would one rewrite the HOC to accept multiple components (unknown number) and return them as siblings (one by one under eachother) together with their respective props?

I assume this is how you'd call a HOC with multiple components as it's just a function:

```
VerticalSlider(MyComponent, MyOtherComponent)
```

I know how to accept and destruct an unknown number of "normal" props, but I'm a but lost here when it comes to passed in components.

Comment: What do you mean return them all together? Will all nested components in the HOC have the same props? Will they all be siblings?

Comment: Yes, the components should be siblings! :)

Comment: Just accept multiple arguments and iterate?

Comment: But what about the component props? I assume it's my bad understanding of curried functions that makes this hard for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

let VerticalSlider = (...komponents) => {
  return (props) => (
    <div className='slider'>
      { komponents.map((K, i) => <K {...props.ps[i]} /> ) }
    </div>
  );
};

const Apple = props =>
  <div>{ props.name }</div>;

const Orange = props =>
  <div>{ props.desc }</div>;

const MyComp = VerticalSlider(Apple, Orange);

const App = () =>
  <div>
    Hello
    <MyComp 
      ps={[{ name: 'apple' }, { desc: 'orange' }]} />
  </div>

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

But it's a little ugly and your coworkers will hate you. Keep it simple and don't overthink it. Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fgulxk?file=index.js)